# jQuery Toggle not working on generated divs

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have a form that generates divs. I need to add information below the div that toggles show/hide on click. I have all the functionality working but I cannot get the toggle action to work on the generated divs.

The fiddle is here, http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/BMX4J/20/

I have made a static test div that works, but when I generate a div it dosent work although when I look at the code both divs are identical.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to `$('#toggleshow').live('click', function()` ...

http://jsfiddle.net/BMX4J/21/

Comment: Note, this only supports up to 7 buttons as you're still defining the elements explicitly by ID

Comment: @Phil, I know, everything here can be rewritten, I just answered why it won't work. If OP want's I can rewrite...

Answer (score 1):

You can add the click handler for all current and future buttons using jQuery `live()`, eg

```
$('.div_menu_button').live('click', function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/BMX4J/22/